# c# audio library - wmp or other

Tags: c#, audio, wmp

I looking for a free (for commercial use) library, who can play wav and support play faster and slower - play speed. NAudio doesn't support that.

I try use the WMP player. It support that, but is a little problem. If i try write a example application, all works fine. When i move the code to production, the application was crashed. .NET Framework show me System.BadImageFormatException. I "google" a little and case proved to be compilation mode. In example app i use Mixed platform, but it's compile probably as x86. In production all must be compile as Any platform.

The WMP library (Interop.WmpLib and Interop.axWmpLib) is COM and compiled only on 32bit, so i can't use that with Any platform - i can't change an platform for x86.

Somebody maybe have fix for that - other library who works with x86/x64 or any tip for use WMP Lib in 64 bit ?

Thanks

Comment: Generally questions asking for library suggestions are discouraged because they lead to unproductive debate.  I won't vote it down, but in the future it would be better to ask more implementation specific questions rather than broad library ones like this which are prone to personal preference etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a popular library for this kind of transformations called [SoundTouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/). 
From their website:

> SoundTouch is an open-source audio processing library for changing the
>   Tempo, Pitch and Playback Rates of audio streams or audio files

Soundtouch [is released under the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL)](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/#features), so you are allowed to use it in commercial projects.

There is .net wrapper for soundtouch called [soundtouchnet](http://code.google.com/p/soundtouchnet/), and they have a sample for using this wrapper with NAudio: [How to use NAudio with SoundTouch](http://code.google.com/p/soundtouchnet/wiki/UsingNAudio)

SoundTouchNet is also LGPL.